# Spark History UI is available but tracking UI errors for in-progress applications

Tags: knox-gateway

I've inherited a cluster that uses knox and am trying to figure out why the Spark history server is available for completed Spark jobs but the Spark UI is not available for in-progress Spark applications.

In this yarn UI (which is exposed via Knox) there are 5 completed yarn applications and 1 in-progress yarn application. All are spark applications:
[image: yarn UI exposed via knox]

In the Tracking UI columns the available links are:

- https://my-knox-endpoint/gateway/my-cluster/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0001
- https://my-knox-endpoint/gateway/my-cluster/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0002
- https://my-knox-endpoint/gateway/my-cluster/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0003
- https://my-knox-endpoint/gateway/my-cluster/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0004
- https://my-knox-endpoint/gateway/my-cluster/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0005
- https://my-knox-endpoint/gateway/my-cluster/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0006

The five links pertaining to the completed jobs all successfully bring up the Spark History server UI for those jobs. If I issue `cat ${GATEWAY_HOME}/logs/gateway-audit.log` I can see the following appear when I hit any of those five links:

> 20/01/27 15:50:55 ||55bef3f3-a52f-4790-97d0-bd6e5076a293|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.0.229|YARNUI||||access|uri|/gateway/my-cluster-name/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0001|unavailable|Request method: GET
>   20/01/27 15:50:55 ||55bef3f3-a52f-4790-97d0-bd6e5076a293|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.0.229|YARNUI||||dispatch|uri|http://my-cluster-name-m:8088/proxy/application_1580137635209_0001|unavailable|Request method: GET
>   **20/01/27 15:50:55 ||55bef3f3-a52f-4790-97d0-bd6e5076a293|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.0.229|YARNUI||||dispatch|uri|http://my-cluster-name-m:8088/proxy/application_1580137635209_0001|success|Response status: 302
>
>   20/01/27 15:50:55 |||audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.0.229|YARNUI||||access|uri|/gateway/my-cluster-name/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0001|success|Response status: 302**
>   20/01/27 15:50:55 ||f7617e15-3bf4-4a8c-9701-9785894d7884|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.0.234|SPARKHISTORYUI||||access|uri|/gateway/my-cluster-name/sparkhistory/history/application_1580137635209_0001/1|unavailable|Request method: GET
>   20/01/27 15:50:55 ||f7617e15-3bf4-4a8c-9701-9785894d7884|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.0.234|SPARKHISTORYUI||||dispatch|uri|http://my-cluster-name-m:18080/history/application_1580137635209_0001/1/|unavailable|Request method: GET
>   20/01/27 15:50:55 ||f7617e15-3bf4-4a8c-9701-9785894d7884|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.0.234|SPARKHISTORYUI||||dispatch|uri|http://my-cluster-name-m:18080/history/application_1580137635209_0001/1/|success|Response status: 30

and lots and lots of other log records for Spark History UI resources. All good. Notice the 302 record (redirect)

However, if I hit the link for the in-progress application I get sent to http://my-cluster-name-m:18080/history/application_1580137635209_0006/1 which is the cluster master node, and the following displayed:
[image]

In the logs I see:

> 20/01/27 15:58:38 ||aec261d3-7ecc-43a7-8815-d7185ee13833|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.1.130|YARNUI||||access|uri|/gateway/my-cluster-name/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0006|unavailable|Request method: GET
>   20/01/27 15:58:38 ||aec261d3-7ecc-43a7-8815-d7185ee13833|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.1.130|YARNUI||||dispatch|uri|http://my-cluster-name-m:8088/proxy/application_1580137635209_0006|unavailable|Request method: GET
>   20/01/27 15:58:38 ||aec261d3-7ecc-43a7-8815-d7185ee13833|audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.1.130|YARNUI||||dispatch|uri|http://my-cluster-name-m:8088/proxy/application_1580137635209_0006|success|Response status: 200
>   20/01/27 15:58:38 |||audit|109.231.200.210, 165.225.80.109, 34.102.220.138, 130.211.1.130|YARNUI||||access|uri|/gateway/my-cluster-name/yarn/proxy/application_1580137635209_0006|success|Response status: 200

Notice there are no 302 records there.

Edit: Since originally posting this I have noticed that if i click on the Tracking UI link **immediately** after the application starts then I am taken to the details of the yarn application:

[image: yarn app details]

A few seconds later clicking on the same link will take me to the error as shown above.

I'm a bit lost at this point. Can anyone help explain why I can't view the Spark UI for in-progress applications? Any pointers as to how I can diagnose would be welcomed.

Comment: Something seems to be off in the logs, the url that is failing is for `application_1580137635209_0006` but the failure audit logs are for application `application_1580137635209_0007`. It would be better if you file a [Knox JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa), also include relevant logs from `gateway.log` file. Logs with DEBUG enabled would be much more useful.

This looks more like a rewrite issue, do you see any errors in `gateway.log` file ?

Comment: @SandeepMore You are correct, that's my bad, apologies. I grabbed the logs from the tail of gateway-audit.log which just happened to be for `application_1580137635209_0007`. I intended to edit them to make them consistent with the screenshot but I forgot to do so in the second batch of log records. I have now done so.

Comment: Any idea how to enable DEBUG logging? I googled for it and found https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-enable-debug-logging-for-Knox/td-p/211479 but the answer there only refers to using Ambari, which we are not using.

Comment: Ignore previous question, I think I've found it {GATEWAY_HOME}/conf/gateway-log4j.properties

Comment: No worries, happens to me all the time. Note on logs, if you want more fine grain logs you can turn on Wire debugging in the log4j properties, it is noisy but can be useful in seeing http headers that are sent and received by Knox to the backend service.

Comment: @SandeepMore Thx for your help. I found the problem and posted an answer.

Comment: Great ! glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer is rather embarrassing. The cause was simply that the spark UI was not enabled. Changing setting `spark.ui.enabled` to `true` solved this particular problem.